# How to get Propel model generator to properly pluralize nouns?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and Propel 1.6. I was confounded at first by various classnames that used improper pluralization.

For example some table relations were things like CommerceItemss, which was easily traced down in my schema.yml where I specified plural instead of singular table names.

After I corrected that, I was still left with one more type of error in the auto generated classes. Namely, I had a table named "Match" which Propel was pluralizing to Matchs.

For example, lines like:

```
        if (null === $this->matchsScheduledForDeletion) {
 ...
            $this->matchsScheduledForDeletion = clone $this->collMatchs;
```

So I'm left with the question of, "how to get Propel to pluralize properly"?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was buried deep in the Propel ORM docs:

http://propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration.html

Namely, edit your default.properties:

```
./plugins/sfPropelORMPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/generator/default.properties
./plugins/propel/generator/default.properties
```

Look for the line that says:

```
propel.builder.pluralizer.class = builder.util.DefaultEnglishPluralizer
```

Replace with:

```
propel.builder.pluralizer.class = builder.util.StandardEnglishPluralizer
```

It handles the problem with Match->Matchs properly (and I presume would also handle Category->Categories, etc.) so this could be the solution if you have a similar problem.

Comment: Great find! You should accept your answer so that people looking for this issue can see that your issue has a solution.

Comment: Thanks jakerella, I can apparently "accept your own answer in 2 days". :)